# Order the results of a query by the same order as the IN statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM campaigns where campaign_id IN ( 'idStrOne', 'idStrTwo', 'idStrThree' );
```

The results of which are being ordered by the primary key of the table campaigns which is 'id'. This is not the order I want.

I want the results to come back in the same order as the arguments to the IN function. So in this case the order I want is

```
idStrOne, idStrTwo, idStrThree
```

How do I get this order?

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a CASE expression in the ORDER BY Clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM campaigns 
WHERE campaign_id IN ( 'idStrOne', 'idStrTwo', 'idStrThree' )
ORDER BY 
(CASE campaign_id WHEN 'idStrOne' THEN 1 WHEN 'idStrTwo' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END);
```

Comment: +1 love the case statement in the order by. Use it all the time, such a valuable tool!